# Xamarin Data Template, issues using custom controls and views

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

(This question builds off of my original one here: [MVVM add elements dynamically to scrollview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60209412/mvvm-add-elements-dynamically-to-scrollview))

So I have successfully created my custom DataTemplateSelector, however, when I render the page it is on I get errors stating things like:

```
Type customControls:NoHighlightCell not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Company.MyProduct.CustomControls'
customViews:TimeView not found in xmlns clr-namespace:Company.MyProduct.CustomViews'
```

Both of them are defined at the root of my ResourceDictionary.xaml using the following:

```
xmlns:customViews="clr-namespace:Company.MyProduct.CustomViews"
xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:Company.MyProduct.CustomControls"
```

If I remove them, and instead just bring the xaml code in the views, and default to using the regular controls, then it has no issue compiling and rendering the elements. So my question is, do data templates just not support external views and custom controls? These views and controls work fine in my other xaml files.

Also makes me wonder whether or not they will support behaviors as well, because that would be blocker.

The project layout where all of this lives is:

Platform (Folder)

- Company.MyProduct (Project)

  - CustomControls (Folder)
  - CustomViews (Folder)
  - XamarinBehaviors (Folder)

So as you can see, they should be all in the same assembly. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: you need to check that the namespaces you are using match the actual namespaces in the xaml.cs for each view/control.  The folder hierarchy and the namespaces will generally match, but this NOT always true.

Comment: @Jason I have checked, and I am confident that is the case. For instance, my custom InputView is defined under the MyCompany.Product.CustomViews namespace. When I try to just have it in the template as the only external view, it still errors out. Do I need to specify something more in the xmlns  declaration?

Comment: also check the names of the classes match, that they are public, and that they are in the same project as the page you are calling them from

Comment: As far I can tell, they are indeed that

Comment: Check whether x:Class in xaml is correct assembly+name. Try clearing bin/obj and restart the solution. If you are on Mac delete .vs folder in the solution root folder

Comment: Hi ,  data templates supports custom controls , you can share the sample code here .

Comment: So interestingly, I decided to approach it slightly  differently. And I think it works now much better. I deleted my ResourceDictionary.xaml, created a new folder where I load my template, and in those templates using the custom controls is fine. Biggest difference is that the individual .xaml files (for the templates) start off with being a <ViewCell> this is also good for me as now i can also see it calling their code behind which allows me to ensure proper setting of the binding context

Comment: I will post some of my code today once I am happy with its overall performance

Answer (score 0):

So what I had to do was the following:

- As mentioned, I deleted my ResourceDictionary.xaml file, as I did not need it. All I needed was the CustomTemplateSelector.cs class
- I then decided to remake the custom views I had, but instead of them being  they are . Note that in the dictionary.xaml i deleted i just coped over the  part of those views, whilst wrapping them in a , perhaps that was insufficient.
- Example:

  ```
  <Label Text="{Binding Label}"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontSize="14"
                    VerticalOptions="Start"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

  <StackLayout
          HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
          VerticalOptions="Start"
          Spacing="0"
          Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
          Orientation="Vertical">

      <customcontrols:BorderlessDatePicker
           x:Name="SNDate"
           Date="{Binding SnDate, Mode=TwoWay}"                       
           VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
           HeightRequest="30"
           FontSize="14"
           HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>

      <BoxView HeightRequest="1"
               BackgroundColor="{Binding FieldColor}" 
               Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
               HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
               VerticalOptions="Start"/>
  </StackLayout>

  <Label Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}"
             TextColor="Red"
             Margin="0, 10, 0, 0"
             IsVisible="{Binding ValidationRequired}"
             VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             FontSize="14"/>
  ```

This appears to have solved my woes, now it properly hits the code behind where we initialize the component, along with binding its event handlers and the like.